# Laravel Eloquent check if json multidimensional array contains certain index and value

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I hope someone can help me with the following.

I have a simple table/model named 'activities' with an column called 'attributes', here I store an json array with some slugs. Each attribute can also have sub childs (terms).

```
{"attribute":{"adventure":{"terms":{"parasailing":"1","kitesurfing":"1","atv-biking":"1"}},"water-sport":{"terms":{"diving":"1","snorkeling":"1","parasailing":"1","jetski":"1"}}}}
```

Now I like to get all activities where the array contains a certain terms slug for example 'parasailing'. But I can't get it to work. I've already searched multiple articles and other questions with no luck.

The code I'm using:

```
$activities = Activity::whereJsonContains('attributes', ['attribute.*.terms.'.$slug.'' => 1])->get();
```

I hope someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct but you need to slightly modify it to match the nested structure of your JSON data. Specifically, you need to use the -> operator to access nested keys in the JSON array. Here's how you can do it

```
    $activities = Activity::get()->filter(function ($activity) use ($slug) {
        $attributes = json_decode($activity->attributes, true);
        if (isset($attributes['attributes'])) {
            $attributes = $attributes['attributes'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
            if (isset($attribute['terms'][$slug]) && $attribute['terms'][$slug] == '1') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it still returns null.

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry, I did not know whereJsonContains does not support wildcards.
i am updating me code so if that may work

Comment: thanks but somehow it still returns null. I have tried both queries.

Comment: when I do a dd on the $attributes I get back an array:

array:1 [▼
  "attributes" => array:2 [▼
    "adventure" => array:1 [▶]
    "water-sport" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
]

However I get an error saying its a Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Any idea?

Comment: @Adriaan it seems there is one more nested level I am updating the code again

Comment: This works!! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Adriaan glad to know it worked. I was trying the code with no data available actually :(